# Does CSMA/CA have anti-DoS measures, and if yes which?

Tags: ieee-802.11, security, ddos

So as far as i understand, you can deny other devices access to a WiFi by flooding the channel they are on with data, so that the channel is never "idle", thus preventing other devices from using it - with multiple antenas it probably wouldnt be an issue either to flood all 11 channels that 2.4GHz has.

The thing is, ive never heard of such an attack, which makes me think that it is not as easy as that. Did i missunderstand something, or is this just not possibly because there are security measures against that?

Comment: At least in the U.S., it would be very easy to get caught and face some very stiff fines and/or federal prison time. Back in the '70s when CB radios were all the rage, you needed a license that was inexpensive simple to get, but many people thought, "they can't catch me," but the FCC proved them wrong.

Comment: Actually, not that easy, good buddy. The ISM bands have less restrictions than other radio services.  You'd have to show malicious intent or at least gross negligence.  Of course, IANAL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite easy to create a DoS attack on the 2.4 Ghz band.  In fact, every time you turn on your microwave oven, you're creating a DoS attack on channel 9.  There are wireless video cameras (and some old cordless phones) that also use the 2.4Ghz band.  They also are good DoS tools.

In practice, you have to be close to the AP or client in order to transmit enough power to create an effective attack.  That means you need to be in close proximity to your target, which increases your chances of being discovered -- most attackers don't want that risk.

Comment: Where does the need to be close to the AP come from? Is there a built-in prioritization for stronger signals? Say when i am far away from the AP and in the middle of a transmission, would the AP just cut me off and listen to a device thats closer instead?

Comment: You need to be close enough to the client or AP so that your signal strength interferes with the target signal enough to render it useless or activate the clear channel assessment threshold.  The farther you are from either, the stronger your signal needs to be.  At some point, you will need so strong a signal that you become conspicuous.